# Systemback equivalent for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: systemback

Hi I was just about to add the repository for installing systemback, and it has informed me it does not support my version of Ubuntu.

Is there something equivalent that I can install?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `systemback`, but you might check out `Timeshift`.

Comment: thanks for the tip and terrifying alias once read in my head

Comment: re: "terrifying alias once read in my head"... you lost me.

Comment: ok that happens a lot and it's usually a good rule of thumb that I don't try to elaborate

Comment: adam@ there's a way to install it from file you can see how  here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280782/bootable-backup-of-system-partition/1281648#1281648

Comment: ok thanks pat I dont currently have an ubuntu OS but appreciate the effort