# Bootable backup of system partition

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm returning to Linux and my MythTV and Plex box after a couple of years hiatus. My current system drive is 750GB with a 20GB root partition on /dev/sda9, a 204M boot partition on /dev/sda1 and a 2.9G swap partition on /dev/sda2.

I want to backup my system to a 32G SSD (only one partition – /dev/sdd1) and to keep it backed up with a nightly cron job using rsync. I have done a dd of the / partition to sdd1 and have updated it using rsync (using the options -avxHAWX --delete-before --numeric-ids). The boot partition and grub folder seem to have been copied to the SSD.

I am struggling to make the SSD bootable. I have put a boot flag on /dev/sdd1 using gparted. I have chrooted into /dev/sdd1 and done a grub-install and update-grub. I set /dev/sdd as the first boot drive in BIOS and disconnected /dev/sda. However, sdd1 fails to boot (went into emergency mode).

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify the purpose of your backup. Is it to save your data, or to save your system in case you muck up and want to backtrack, or something else? And, why do you need `/dev/ssd1` to be bootable? Telling use this will help to answer your question in the most helpful way, because as always there are multiple ways to go about what you want. It might help to tell us which version of Ubuntu you are using (e.g. Xubuntu 18.04).

Comment: The main purpose of the backup is in case of sda disk failure but it is also handy in case I muck up /dev/sda9 including with a failed release upgrade. I am on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and will upgrade to 20.04.1 LTS once I get the /dev/sdd1 backup sorted. I need /dev/sdd1 to be bootable so that I can boot from it if I can no longer boot from /dev/sda.

Comment: You cannot use dd and keep drive mounted.  Also dd is only for same size to same size image copy. DD will be an exact copy drive/partition and then you have duplicate UUIDs and if newer gpt partitioning duplicate GUIDs. You have to go into one system or other and change every reference to UUID & reinstall grub. Often easier to just do new install and copy configuration files /home, perhaps some in /etc & databases for your plex & Myth.

Comment: I completely agree with @oldfred on this one. I have copied drives between computers (using [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/)), and the UUID was indeed a complicating factor, as well as Grub. I suggest: (1) Create a bootable USB stick with the Ubuntu 20.04 ISO. (2) Install a fresh copy of Ubuntu 20.04 on `sdd1`. (3) Set up `sdd1` fully, and use that from here on. (4) After a month of successful running `sdd1`, repurpose `sda1` as a backup drive, copying not the entire system but just all the data and the configuration files (as @oldfred mentioned). Clean installations are more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input. I know a fresh install is the sensible way to go - but even if I did a fresh install - which I probably will do in due course - I would still want a bootable clone that was updated by rsync on a daily or hourly basis in case my system drive crashes.

I have managed to get sdd bootable and the cloning looks to be working well. I generated a new UUID for the partition (using sudo tune2fs -U random /dev/sdd1) and edited the clone's /etc/fstab. I had already labelled the clone partition so I used the label in /etc/fstab although I'm sure I could just have used the new UUID.

I discovered a useful utility called boot-repair -https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/. I used it but it didn't work - because, as I realised afterwards, I had rsynced to the clones /etc/fstab. (I have now excluded /etc/fstab and some other files/ directories from the rsync).

I am not sure exactly which step solved the issue - it seems like generating the new UUID made the difference (and obviously editing the clone's /etc/fstab) - after which I chrooted into the clone and did a grub-install and update-grub.

I will now upgrade to Ubuntu (probably Xubuntu) 20.04, stop rsyncing to the clone, and recommence the rsyncing after a couple of days if all is good with the 20.04 upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can backup your actual system using **Systemback** https://sourceforge.net/projects/systemback-source-1-9-4/. The option to use is **COPY** that allows you copy
the whole system with or without home data.  You have to mount where your system have to be copied and then you have to indicate where to put your Bootloader. You can also copy all your user data (/home/user) or not.

[image]

For the installation you can download it from sourceforge and then:

```
cd Downloads/
tar xvf systemback-install_pack-1.9.4.tar.gz 
cd systemback-install_pack-1.9.4/ 
chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.